# python Return value none

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some clarification. When I execute the below code with the function using `return`, I am getting different behavior from when I use the function using `print`. I am getting the same output but it is printing a word "none" which is not in the program.

```
import random 

# **With Return**   
def getAnswer(answerNumber): 
    if answerNumber == 1: 
        return 'It is certain' 
    elif answerNumber == 2: 
        return 'It is decidedly so' 
    elif answerNumber == 3: 
        return 'Yes' 

# **With Print**    
def getAnswer2(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        print('It is certain')
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        print('It is decidedly so')
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        print('Yes')

r = random.randint(1, 3) 
fortune = getAnswer(r) 
print(fortune)

fortune = getAnswer2(r) 
print(fortune)
```

The output is for example

```
Yes
Yes
None
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function you use with print statements does not have a return value. However you are printing the return of that function with the line `print(fortune)`. So what should it print if there is nothing there? Well, it prints `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Every Python function implicitly returns `None`, unless you explicitly return something else.

In your first section, you are explicitly returning the string, and printing that value.

In your second section, you are printing the message, and then printing the return value (`None`, implicitly).